# Extjs fieldLabel in Ext.tree.Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, textfield, treepanel

I would like to have a "welcome text" before the directory tree in my Ext.tree.Panel, so something like that:

[image: example]

I wrote this code, but it doesn't work:

```
Ext.define('MyProject.view.permissions.Example', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',

    requires: [
        'MyProject.view.permissions.ExampleController'
    ],

    controller: 'example',
    xtype: 'exampleWindow',
    store: 'examplePermissionTree',
    rootVisible: false,
    rowLines: false,
    //headerPosition: 'left',
    lines: false,
    autoLoad: false,
    autoExpand: false,

    items :[{
           xtype: 'displayfield',
           fieldLabel: 'welcome text',
           name: 'welcome',
     }],

    columns: {
        items: [ {
                    xtype: 'treecolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'text',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    xtype: 'booleancolumn',
                    flex: 0.3,
                    dataIndex: 'granted',
                    trueText: Strings.permissionGranted,
                    falseText: Strings.permissionNotGranted
                }, {
                    xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
                    flex: 0.2,
                    widget: {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        handler: 'onGroupClick',
                        text: Strings.permissionGrant

                    }
                }
            ]
        }
});
```

My problem is that the text doesn't appear. It appears only the directory tree.
How Could I fix it? Should I use another approach?

Answer (score 2):

**1. Use Tools instead of items**

Using `tools` instead of items can solve the problem. An array of Ext.panel.Tool configs/instances to be added to the header tool area. The code should be like

```
tools :[{
       xtype: 'displayfield',
       fieldLabel: 'welcome text',
       name: 'welcome',
      }],
```

**2. Use label in lieu of displayfield**

```
     tools :[{
            xtype: 'label',
            fieldLabel: 'welcome text',
            name: 'welcome',
           }],
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Is it also possible to insert the text not in the header, but under ,like in the image? because now it appeasr in the blue area...Or is not possible and I should fix it by CSS (I mean so to have white background, align left etc.)?